# SSIS: How to step through code in a Script Component or Task?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I would really like to be able to see my code in action because it is failing, but i don't know where.

Answer (score 1):

Script Tasks will let you set breakpoints and step through them.  Script components (in data flows) are a little trickier.  I usually just sprinkle them with MessageBoxes to help me figure out where the code is failing and what the values of key variables are.